# Wordpress User Submissions

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upload, submission

I want to be able to modify my Wordpress theme to be able to do exactly what this page does.
http://www.planetminecraft.com/resources/texture_packs/

I know first one would have to allow user uploads, but i would like to moderate them as well. 
Does anyone know of a Wordpress plugin or solution to this problem?

ALSO: If possible, I need to add meta to the file upload (eg. Image, Title, Description)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'this page' 'does' a lot. what feature exactly do you need ? be more specific about your question/read the faq!

Comment: Users Upload files. title them, add image, etc. Then have a listing of all uploaded files with image, title, link to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there's no plugin yet doing something like that. But maybe you can find one yourself in the [wordpress plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=file%20upload)!

Depending on your programming skills, you could just write one yourself. The idea here would be to create a folder named as a auto-incrementing id, which is equal to an id in the database that you create simultaniously together with all the information stored in the DB.